# OAuth получение токена CURL easypay

Tags: php, curl, oauth

цель получить токен от api.easypay.ua, имеется рабочий код который надо переделать под php:

```
curl -X POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "PartnerKey: easypay-v2" \
    --header "locale: UA" \
    --header "AppId: b826a751-0571-47c1-9709-dd639c364919" \
    --header "PageId: bfe30747-ed11-4143-919b-ed2f91c65114" \
    -d "client_id=easypay-v2&grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass" \

   "https://api.easypay.ua/api/token"
```

вот что получилось у меня на php:

```php
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.easypay.ua/api/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_id=easypay-v2&grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Partnerkey: easypay-v2';
$headers[] = 'Appid: b826a751-0571-47c1-9709-dd639c364919';
$headers[] = 'Locale: UA';
$headers[] = 'Pageid: bfe30747-ed11-4143-919b-ed2f91c65114';
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?
выдает ошибку на сайте: {"error":{"errorCode":"NEED_SAFETY_CHECK","title":"Помилка системи","description":"Помилка системи","errorMessage":"Потрібно перевірити безпеку","fieldErrors":[]}}

Comment: по моему не хватате куда послать  CURLOPT_URL там не должно быть locale а должен быть адрес https://api.easypay.ua/api/token

Comment: ой то не правильно скопировало, все верно там стоит адрес но все равно не правильно

Comment: используй украинский ip (proxy/openvpn) в запросе, тогда будет ок

Comment: Хорошо бы описать как именно его использовать, а не просто общие слова)

Comment: А почему первый пример с curl работает?